# Unmounting a RUN cache-type mount in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, caching, dockerfile, mount, unmount

In a Dockerfile, I am mounting a cache:

```
RUN  --mount=type=cache,target=/opt/conda/pkgs \
     ...
```

I would like this mount to be valid for the duration of either

1. just this RUN command
2. until it is unmounted a few layers further down

Is there a way to do this?

*I'm not able to find any reference in the documentation.*

Answer (score 0):

Try making use of the multi stage Dockerfile

For example :-

```
FROM BASE_IMAGE:tag AS base
RUN  --mount=type=cache,target=/opt/conda/pkgs \
 ...


FROM BASE_IMAGE:tag AS app
RUN mkdir /some/place
COPY --from=base "/opt/conda/pkgs"
```